# Samsung Knox Scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, mdm, samsung-knox

We have an Android Application that is distributed through a Samsung Knox profile.  In the application there is a change password fragment that has a ScrollView nested within a RelativeLayout and containing a single RelativeLayout.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.view.fragments.ChangeUserPasswordFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/create_profile_button_background"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel_change_password"
                style="@style/LatoRegularWhiteBackgroundButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin"
                android:text="@string/back" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Header Bar-->
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/update_password_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/outer_layout"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/form_field_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/account_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/account_horizontal_margin"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/LatoLightTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                        android:text="@string/change_password"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/h1_font_size" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/error_bar_password_change"
                        layout="@layout/error_bar"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/error_message_label_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/error_message_field_height"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/create_profile_fields_top_margin"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/old_password"
                        layout="@layout/form_field"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/form_field_width"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/create_profile_fields_top_margin" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/new_password"
                        layout="@layout/form_field"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/form_field_width"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/create_profile_fields_top_margin" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/confirm_new_password"
                        layout="@layout/form_field"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/form_field_width"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/create_profile_fields_top_margin" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <!--Save Button-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/outer_layout">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/save_button"
                        style="@style/PrimaryButton"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/action_button_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_button_height"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/primary_button"
                        android:text="@string/change_password_save"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </RelativeLayout> <!--/save button-->
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When outside of Knox's kiosk mode that application can scroll the content by dragging upward or downward with a touch gesture.  When in kiosk mode the user cannot scroll the content, except by pressing "Next" in the soft keyboard, shifting the focus to the next field.  We need the user to be able to scroll by dragging upward or downward in kiosk mode as well as out of it.